# *.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: windows-xp

Recently I bought a VGA card, "ATI Radeon HD4650", and after that I installed it on my PC, I can't run any .exe files just from my CD-Rom! Even when I attempted to install the driver of the VGA Card, I couldn't do that.

So I downloaded it and installed it with no problems. After that when I try to install some games from a DVD (more than 5 different games I have tried). It prompted me with: `setup.exe is not a valid win32 application` so I couldn't install the game, in addition I need to say that there's nothing wrong with the DVD's and my DVD-Rom.

What should I do?

Comment: did these executables work on that computer before installing the new VGA card?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried it before, but it does work on another PC

Comment: well, I need to mention another thing that I have tried, as far as I see, I cant run any .exe file from my DVD-R/W Rom !

Comment: don't close this question as a duplicate; close the other question as a duplicate of this one: http://superuser.com/questions/121182/cant-run-exe-files-from-my-dvd-r-w-rom-win-xp-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to reinstall your drivers for the CD/DVD-ROM drives.  Then reinstall the drivers for the VGA card and see if that works.  If this doesn't work, uninstall the VGA card and see if your executables work again.  This ma help you troubleshoot where the problems started.

Comment: I just update my DVD Rom Firmware and it solved my problem, thanks