# Can't Run .exe files from my DVD-R/W Rom win XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, optical-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [*.exe is not a valid win32 application](https://superuser.com/questions/121160/exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Hi everybody

In my windows XP Pro I can't run any .exe file from my DVD Rom, but I can run them on my hard drive, Even I can't copy anything from a DVD to my hard drive. and when I run .exe file there is some prompt message like "setup.exe is not a valid win32 application" or something like that.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: please don't post the same question multiple times.  if this indeed a separate issue, you need to clarify how it's different for us.  earlier question: http://superuser.com/questions/121160/exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked my DVD rom model in Device manager section, and update the firmware. and it does solve my problem. thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Well, just based on the info you have in your post, it looks to me like you have a 32 bit system and are trying to run a 64 bit application on it. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a cyclic redundancy error, due to an unreadable disc. Try cleaning it.